# How to get the set of rows which are having same cut-off marks?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Name      Age      Cut-off
--------------------------
Ram       22        89.50
Ganesh    22        66.00
Sam       22        92.00
Albert    22        89.50
Kannan    22        65.45   
John      22        66.00
```

> In above table Ram and Albert as well as Ganesh and John having same cut-off value. How can 
>   i get all these rows?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: you're just trying to find dupes? such questions have a few million dupes here.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT `Cut-off`, COUNT(*) totalCOunt
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY `Cut-off`
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON a.`Cut-off` = b.`Cut-off`
```

for faster performance, add an `INDEX` on column `Cut-off`

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/966aa/4)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
select *
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.cutoff = t.cutoff and t2.name <> t.name)
```